# How to implement Pytorch 1D crosscorrelation for long signals in fourier domain?

Tags: python-3.x, gpu, fft, pytorch, cross-correlation

I have a series of signals length n = 36,000 which I need to perform crosscorrelation on. Currently, my cpu implementation in numpy is a little slow. I've heard Pytorch can greatly speed up tensor operations, and provides a way to perform computations in parallel on the GPU. I'd like to explore this option, but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this using the framework.

Because of the length of these signals, I'd prefer to perform the crosscorrelation operation in the frequency domain.

Normally using numpy I'd perform the operation like so:

```py
import numpy as np

signal_length=36000

# make the signals
signal_1 = np.random.uniform(-1,1, signal_length)
signal_2 = np.random.uniform(-1,1, signal_length)

# output target length of crosscorrelation
x_cor_sig_length = signal_length*2 - 1

# get optimized array length for fft computation
fast_length = np.fftpack.next_fast_len(x_cor_sig_length)

# move data into the frequency domain. axis=-1 to perform 
# along last dimension
fft_1 = np.fft.rfft(src_data, fast_length, axis=-1)
fft_2 = np.fft.rfft(src_data, fast_length, axis=-1)

# take the complex conjugate of one of the spectrums. Which one you choose depends on domain specific conventions
fft_1 = np.conj(fft_1)


fft_multiplied = fft_1 * fft_2

# back to time domain. 
prelim_correlation = np.fft.irfft(result, x_corr_sig_length, axis=-1)

# shift the signal to make it look like a proper crosscorrelation,
# and transform the output to be purely real

final_result = np.real(np.fft.fftshift(prelim_correlation),axes=-1)).astype(np.float64)
```

Looking at the Pytorch documentation, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent for numpy.conj(). I'm also not sure if/how I need to implement a fftshift after the irfft operation.

So how would you go about writing a 1D crosscorrelation in Pytorch using the fourier method?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to be considered.

Python interpreter is very slow, what those vectorization libraries do is to move the workload to a native implementation. In order to make any difference you need to be able to give perform many operations in one python instruction. Evaluating things on GPU follows the same principle, while GPU has more compute power it is slower to copy data to/from GPU.

I adapted your example to process multiple signals simulataneously.

```python
import numpy as np
def numpy_xcorr(BATCH=1, signal_length=36000):
    # make the signals
    signal_1 = np.random.uniform(-1,1, (BATCH, signal_length))
    signal_2 = np.random.uniform(-1,1, (BATCH, signal_length))

    # output target length of crosscorrelation
    x_cor_sig_length = signal_length*2 - 1

    # get optimized array length for fft computation
    fast_length = next_fast_len(x_cor_sig_length)

    # move data into the frequency domain. axis=-1 to perform 
    # along last dimension
    fft_1 = np.fft.rfft(signal_1, fast_length, axis=-1)
    fft_2 = np.fft.rfft(signal_2 + 0.1 * signal_1, fast_length, axis=-1)

    # take the complex conjugate of one of the spectrums. 
    fft_1 = np.conj(fft_1)


    fft_multiplied = fft_1 * fft_2

    # back to time domain. 
    prelim_correlation = np.fft.irfft(fft_multiplied, fast_length, axis=-1)

    # shift the signal to make it look like a proper crosscorrelation,
    # and transform the output to be purely real

    final_result = np.fft.fftshift(np.real(prelim_correlation), axes=-1)
    return final_result, np.sum(final_result)
```

Since torch 1.7 we have the [torch.fft](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.0/fft.html?highlight=fft#torch.fft.fft) module that provides an interface similar to numpy.fft, the fftshift is missing but the same result can be obtained with [torch.roll](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.0/generated/torch.roll.html?highlight=roll#torch.roll). Another point is that numpy uses by default 64-bit precision and torch will use 32-bit precision.

The fast length consists in choosing smooth numbers (those having that are factorized in to small prime numbers, and I suppose you are familiar with this subject).

```py
def next_fast_len(n, factors=[2, 3, 5, 7]):
    '''
      Returns the minimum integer not smaller than n that can
      be written as a product (possibly with repettitions) of
      the given factors.
    '''
    best = float('inf')
    stack = [1]
    while len(stack):
        a = stack.pop()
        if a >= n:
            if a < best:
                best = a;
                if best == n:
                    break; # no reason to keep searching
        else:
            for p in factors:
                b = a * p;
                if b < best:
                    stack.append(b)
    return best;
```

Then the torch implementation goes

```py
import torch;
import torch.fft
def torch_xcorr(BATCH=1, signal_length=36000, device='cpu', factors=[2,3,5], dtype=torch.float):
    signal_length=36000
    # torch.rand is random in the range (0, 1)
    signal_1 = 1 - 2*torch.rand((BATCH, signal_length), device=device, dtype=dtype)
    signal_2 = 1 - 2*torch.rand((BATCH, signal_length), device=device, dtype=dtype)

    # just make the cross correlation more interesting
    signal_2 += 0.1 * signal_1;

    # output target length of crosscorrelation
    x_cor_sig_length = signal_length*2 - 1

    # get optimized array length for fft computation
    fast_length = next_fast_len(x_cor_sig_length, [2, 3])

    # the last signal_ndim axes (1,2 or 3) will be transformed
    fft_1 = torch.fft.rfft(signal_1, fast_length, dim=-1)
    fft_2 = torch.fft.rfft(signal_2, fast_length, dim=-1)

    # take the complex conjugate of one of the spectrums. Which one you choose depends on domain specific conventions

    fft_multiplied = torch.conj(fft_1) * fft_2

    # back to time domain. 
    prelim_correlation = torch.fft.irfft(fft_multiplied, dim=-1)

    # shift the signal to make it look like a proper crosscorrelation,
    # and transform the output to be purely real

    final_result = torch.roll(prelim_correlation, (fast_length//2,))
    return final_result, torch.sum(final_result);
```

And here a code to test the results

```py
import time
funcs = {'numpy-f64': lambda b: numpy_xcorr(b, factors=[2,3,5], dtype=np.float64), 
         'numpy-f32': lambda b: numpy_xcorr(b, factors=[2,3,5], dtype=np.float32), 
         'torch-cpu-f64': lambda b: torch_xcorr(b, device='cpu', factors=[2,3,5], dtype=torch.float64), 
         'torch-cpu': lambda b: torch_xcorr(b, device='cpu', factors=[2,3,5], dtype=torch.float32), 
         'torch-gpu-f64': lambda b: torch_xcorr(b, device='cuda', factors=[2,3,5], dtype=torch.float64),
         'torch-gpu': lambda b: torch_xcorr(b, device='cuda', factors=[2,3,5], dtype=torch.float32),
         }
times ={}
for batch in [1, 10, 100]:
    times[batch] = {}
    for l, f in funcs.items():
        t0 = time.time()
        t1, t2 = f(batch)
        tf = time.time()
        del t1
        del t2
        times[batch][l] = 1000 * (tf - t0) / batch;
```

I obtained the following results

[image: Run times for 32-bit and 64-bit precision, varying batch size, using numpy, pytorch-cpu and pytorch-gpu, with 5-smooth FFT length]

[image: Run times for 32-bit and 64-bit precision, varying batch size, using numpy, pytorch-cpu and pytorch-gpu, with 5-smooth FFT length]

And what surprised myself is the result when the numbers are not so smooth e.g. using 17-smooth length the torch implementation is so much better that I used logarithmic scale here (with batch size 100 the torch gpu was 10000 times faster than numpy with batch size 1).

[image: Run times for 32-bit and 64-bit precision, varying batch size, using numpy, pytorch-cpu and pytorch-gpu, with 5-smooth FFT length]

Remember that these functions are generating the data at the GPU in general we want to copy the final results to the CPU, if we consider the time spent copying the final result to CPU I observed times up to 10x higher than the cross correlation computation (random data generation + three FFTs).