# Speeding up code which integrates a 2D gpuArray matrix using Simpson's Rule

Tags: matlab, optimization, gpu, vectorization

I have a (real) 2D gpuArray, which I am using as part of a larger code, and now am trying to also integrate the array using the [Composite Simpson Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Composite_Simpson%27s_rule) inside my main loop (several 10000 iterations at least). A MWE looks like the following:

```matlab
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MAIN CODE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Ny = 501;    % Dimensions of matrix M
Nx = 503;    %
dx = 0.1;    % Grid spacings
dy = 0.2;    %

M = rand(Ny, Nx, 'gpuArray'); % Initialise a  matrix

for k = 1:10000
    % M = function1(M)  % Apply some other functions to M
    % ... etc ...
    I = simpsons_integration_2D(M, dx, dy, Nx, Ny); % Now integrate M
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Integrator %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function I = simpsons_integration_2D(F, dx, dy, Nx, Ny)
% Integrate the 2D function F with Nx columns and Ny rows, and grid spacings
% dx and dy using Simpson's rule.

% Integrate along x direction (vertically) --> IX is a vector afterwards
sX = sum( F(:,1:2:Nx-2) + 4*F(:,2:2:(Nx-1)) + F(:,3:2:Nx) , 2);
IX = dx/3 * sX;

% Integrate along y direction --> I is a scalar afterwards
sY = sum( IX(1:2:Ny-2) + 4*IX(2:2:(Ny-1)) + IX(3:2:Ny) , 1);
I = dy/3 * sY;
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

The operation of performing the integration is around 850 µs, which is currently a significant part of my code. This was measured using

```matlab
f = @() simpsons_integration_2D(M, dx, dy, Nx, Ny);
t = gputimeit(f)
```

Is there a way to reduce the execution time for integrating the gpuArray matrix?
(The graphics card is the Nvidia Quadro P4000)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the matrix has odd dimensions here is a way to optimize the function:

```
function I = simpsons_integration_2D(F, dx, dy, Nx, Ny)
    sX = 2 * sum(F,2) + 2 * sum (F(:,2:2:(Nx-1)),2) -  F(:,1) - F(:,Nx);
    sY = dx/3 * (2 * sum(sX) + 2 * sum (sX(2:2:(Ny-1))) - sX(1) - sX(Ny));
    I = dy/3 * sY;
end
```

EDIT

A more optimized solution using matrix multiplication:

```
function I = simpsons_integration_2D2(F, dx, dy, Nx, Ny)
  mx = repmat (2,  Nx, 1);
  mx(2:2:(Nx-1)) = 4;
  mx(1) = 1;
  mx(Nx) = 1;
  my = repmat (2,  1, Ny);
  my(2:2:(Ny-1)) = 4;
  my(1) = 1;
  my(Ny) = 1;
  I = (dx*dy/9) * (my * (F * mx));
end
```

If `Nx` and `Ny` are the same you need to compute only one of them `mx` or `my`:

```
function I = simpsons_integration_2D2(F, dx, dy, Nx, Ny)
  mx = repmat (2,  Nx, 1);
  mx(2:2:(Nx-1)) = 4;
  mx(1) = 1;
  mx(Nx) = 1;
  I = (dx*dy/9) * (mx.' * (F * mx));
end
```

If `Nx` and `Ny` are constant you can precompute `mx` outside the function and pass it as a function argument:

```
function I = simpsons_integration_2D2(F, dx, dy, mx)
  I = (dx*dy/9) * (mx.' * (F * mx));
end
```

EDIT:

If both `mx` and `my` can be precomputed the problem is reduced to a dot product:

```
m = reshape (my.' .* mx.', 1, []);

function I = simpsons_integration_2D3(F, dx, dy, m)
  I = (dx*dy/9) * (m * F(:));
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but this actually takes (slightly) longer on my system. gputimeit() returns an execution time of around 950 µs for your version.

Comment: @teeeeee I edited the answer! I think the new method works better.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I need to use your first version (because Nx and Ny are different), but I can still pull mx and my outside the loop. This then clocks in at 210 µs on my machine - a speedup of around x4. Do you think this is the best that can be done, or could you suggest how one might go about improving it further?

Comment: @teeeeee Thanks! If you needed more speed you should not accept my answer to motivate me more to think about that :). In my opinion it cannot be improved further. I may comment here if I guess a better way.

Comment: @teeeeee Try `I = (dx*dy/9) * ((my * F) * mx);` I think it may work better.

Comment: Simply swapping the order of the brackets? ((my * F) * mx) instead of (my * (F * mx)) ?

Comment: I accepted it because you answered it :) demonstrating a way to successfully speed it up!

Comment: Swap the order of brackets, because it takes into account order of data that is column major.

Comment: Interesting. This does indeed reduce the execution time by another 3% to 4%. Great trick. It may seem small, but highlights the difference between rows/columns. I learn so much from questions/answers on this site.

Comment: @teeeeee I updated my answer again and computation is reduced to dot product. I'm not sure if it works better than matrix -vector multiplication.

Comment: It seems like removing the brackes altogether actually reduces the time by another 35%... not sure what is going on, i.e. (dx*dy/9) * my * F * mx

Comment: @teeeeee What about dot product?

Comment: Removing the brackets completely using (dx*dy/9) * my * F * mx reduces time from 210µs to 135µs. Taking the prefactor (dx*dy/9) outside the loop, effectively precalculating it, reduces this to 97µs. Finally, your dot product version (again with prefactor outside the loop), i.e simply I = m * F(:); reduces this even further to 77µs. This is now a speedup of more than x10..

Answer (score 0):

Well I cannot test this for you but there are a few things that may help.

First the axis 1 and then the the axis 2 may make some difference in terms of locality of the modified terms (I don't know if to better or to worse).

```matlab
function I = variation1(F, dx, dy, Nx, Ny)
% Sum each term separately, prevents the creation of a big intermediate matrix
% Multiply outside the summation does only Ny multiplications by 4 instead of Ny*Nx/2
sX = sum(F(:,1:2:Nx-2), 2) + 4*sum(F(:,2:2:(Nx-1)), 2) + sum(F(:,3:2:Nx), 2);
IX = dx/3 * sX;
sY = sum(IX(1:2:Ny-2), 1) + 4*sum(IX(2:2:(Ny-1)), 1) + sum(IX(3:2:Ny) , 1);
I = dy/3 * sY;
end
```

```matlab
function I = variation2(F, dx, dy, Nx, Ny)
% a.
% Sum each term separately, prevents the creation of a big intermediate matrix
% Multiply outside the summation does only Ny multiplications by 4 instead of Ny*Nx/2
% b.
% Notice that the terms 2:3:NX-2 appear in two summations
% Saves Nx*Ny/2 additions at the expense of Ny multiplications by 2
sX = 2*sum(F(:,3:2:Nx-2), 2) + 4*sum(F(:,2:2:(Nx-1)), 2) + F(:,1) + F(:,Nx);
% saves Ny multiplications by moving the constant factor after the next sum
sY = 2*sum(sX(3:2:Ny-2), 1) + 4*sum(sX(2:2:(Ny-1)), 1) + sX(1) + sX(Ny);
I = (dy*dy/9) * sY;
end
```

```matlab
function I = alternate_simpsons_integration_2D(F, dx, dy, Nx, Ny)
% Integrate the 2D function F with Nx columns and Ny rows, and grid spacings
% dx and dy using Simpson's rule.

% Notice that sum(F(:,1:2:Nx-2) + F(:,3:2:Nx)) have all but the end poitns repeated.
IX = 4*sum(F(:,2:2:Nx-1), 2) + 2 * sum(F(:,3:2:Nx-2) , 2) + F(:,1) + F(:,Nx);
disp(size(IX))
% Integrate along y direction --> I is a scalar afterwards
sY = 4*sum(IX(2:2:Ny-1)) + 2*sum(IX(3:2:Ny-2)) + IX(1) + IX(Ny);
I = dy*dy/9 * sY;
end
```

If you think it is better to make a single summation then you can do using the formula `2*(sum(2*F(2:2:end-1) + F(1:2:end-2)) + F(end) - F(1)` that gives the same result but has `Nx*Ny/2` less additions on the first integration. But these options have to be tested in your environment.

#### Transposed implementation

```matlab
function I = transposed_simpsons_integration_2D(F, dx, dy, Nx, Ny)
sY = 2*sum(2*F(2:2:end-1, :) + F(1:2:end-2, :), 1) + F(end, :) - F(1, :);
sX = 2*sum(2*sY(2:2:end-1) + sY(1:2:end-2)) + sY(end) - sY(1);
I = dy*dy/9 * sX;
end
```

Using octave (usually slower than matlab) I get a run time of ~400us per iteration with. This is not the type of workload that will be interesting to run on the GPU. For comparison, randn about 10 times slower than this function.

[image: octave screenshot]

Comment: Hi, thanks but all x3 of these perform slightly worse than the original. gputimeit() returns around 1 ms for all three (compared with the ~850 µs of my original).

Comment: Bear in mind that this example is not a good task for GPU, it is true that it can be parallelised, but it is not computationally expensive. You are doing about 10 operations per element, the time you spend copying the data to the GPU than computing the integral.
Look at this analysis https://stackoverflow.com/a/66118983/12750353

Comment: The array M is already a gpuArray (from some other part of the code), and so is already on the GPU. I'm not sure I understand what you mean about "time spent copying the data". Once it is copied (at the beginning) then there is no more copying right? All further integrations are done on the gpuArray from then on (unless I gather() again at the very end).

Comment: The issue is that I have a bunch of other operations inside the main loop (before this integration is done) which are much faster on the GPU. The only other option I can see would then be to copy back everytime inside the loop using gather(), and perform the integration on the CPU. But surely this would then be worse?

Comment: Yes you are right, it is better to do everything on the GPU.